# How to make ID's generic for different website

Tags: selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, testng, factory-pattern

I am automating tests using selenium webdriver using test ng framework. Here am trying to implement POI and factory Design pattern.
Basically am testing on two websites (Which differs in GUI interface)which has login pages 
Login Name and Password and login button but the challenging part is webelements has different ID in both the websites.
HOw to write a generic methods for this?

For locators i have a an enum class where i take the instance of each value and call it in the method.

Answer (score 0):

As `id` is different than for sure you need to define both elements. There is no such solution for it.
In your testcase you can implement a check which defines that you on which environment and accordingly it will pass the element